# How to check if a value exists in json array? If match is found, delete the key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint column named AllLinks in which im storing array as:

```
[{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"http://www.Link9.com"},   
 {"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"http://www.Link6.com"}]
```

How to check if a value exists in an array of objects and if a match is found, delete the key value pair.

For example if the value Link6 matches, delete the entry completely from the array using javascript/jquery. I tried with:

```
var newA = data.d.results.filter(function (item) return item.AllLinks !== x;});
```

but `item.AllLinks` again returns the complete array itself

as AllLinks is a column in my sharepoint list.

Comment: you want to remove it before or without json decode in js ??

Comment: Note that nothing about this is JSON. I changed the title, description and tags for you.

Comment: But in many json validators it comes out as valid json.Is it really not json and just array of objects?

Answer (score 6):

You can use filter function:

```
var a = [{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"http://www.Link9.com"},{"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"http://www.Link6.com"}]

var newA = a.filter(function (item) {
    return item.AllLinks !== "Link6";
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in such an easy way here:

```js
var jsonArry = [{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"http://www.Link9.com"},{"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"http://www.Link6.com"}];

var value = "Link6";

for(var i=0; i<jsonArry.length; i++){
   if(jsonArry[i].AllLinks === value){
        jsonArry.splice(i,1);
   }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArry));
```

If you are sure that the `value` key is unique then add a `break` keyword inside the `for` loop within `if` after you delete the object so as to prevent unnecessary loops like this,

```
for(var i=0; i<jsonArry.length; i++){
   if(jsonArry[i].AllLinks === value){
       jsonArry.splice(i,1);
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't you see that the array item isn't really removed? You still have `null` in there, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @PeterMader you are right. Thanks for improving. We can use splice in this case.