# Delete key/value pair from json array obtained from ajax response if key is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am fetching data from one list in sharepoint and storing it in json array to pass it onto another function to create a new item in Sharepoint list.The first function is:

```
$.ajax({

    url:  someSharepointListUrl,
    type: "get",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
        var array = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {
            var it=data.d.results[i];
            array.push({
                AllLinks: it.AllLinks,   
                LinkURL: it.LinkURL.Url
            });
        }
        dataCharts=JSON.stringify(array);      
        alert(dataCharts);
        AddDefaultLinks(dataCharts);


    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON.error);
    }
});
```

The item is stored in the list as as:`[{"Name":"Name1","URL":"http://www.name1.com"},{"Name":"Name2","URL":"http://www.name2.com"}]`
The second function which fetches data from list after item is created is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:  url,
    type: "get",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {

        var c = [];
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(data.d.results[0].AllLinks);
        //alert(stringData);
        c.push(JSON.parse(stringData));
        alert(c);

        var xonly = c.filter(function (entry){
            return entry.AllLinks != x; 
        });
       alert(xonly);

    },
    error: function() {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

I need to match if a value exists in this newly created list Item.If yes then delete it eg Lin.
value of c(json array) here is:`[{"Name":"Name1","URL":"http://www.name1.com"},{"Name":"Name2","URL":"http://www.name2.com"}]`

`
entry.AllLinks doesnt filter data here.AllLinks is undefined in entry.AllLinks.Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a value exists in json array? If match is found, delete the key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732680/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-json-array-if-match-is-found-delete-the-key)

Comment: It doesnt work for me.I checked this link

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the desired value inside array, and use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove that object.

Comment: Even this gives undefined value ,objectFound is -1                                               var elementPos = c.map(function(x) {return x.Name; }).indexOf('Name1');
 var objectFound =c[elementPos];
  alert(objectFound);

Comment: Even this is not working and -1 is being returned function isFound(element) {
                return (element === "Name1");
               
            }
            var j=c.findIndex(isFound);
            alert(j);